# Floating point equivalent of \int_case:nnTF

Tags: expl3, latex3

There are several typed pattern-matching commands in expl3, such as `\tl_case`, `\str_case` etc., including `\int_case`, but, notably, there doesn't seem to be a corresponding `\fp_case` for matching floating point values. I am using the current [l3kernel documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) for reference.

Am I missing something trivial or is `\fp_case` actually missing at the moment? If so, I'd appreciate some pointers towards implementing it, as I'm still new at using LaTeX3 internals. TIA.

Comment: It would be a bit pointless, because you can have rounding errors and then `3.1415926535897932` would not match `3.1415926535897931`...

Comment: The short answer is going to be 'there isn't one', but I wonder what you are up to where you feel a floating point 'case' switch makes sense

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik That's true (also in C and other "conventional" languages), I was just wondering about the existence of `\fp_compare` and the possibility of expanding on the same idea. I might very well be misunderstanding something here, though.

Comment: @JosephWright Terrible things.

Comment: @AretsPaeglis With `\fp_compare:nNnTF`, you are often looking for 'more than X' or 'less than X', which doesn't have that issue. Or you are looking for reliable marker values (like exactly zero).

Comment: How do the `=`, `!=`, `<=>` relations from `\fp_compare:nNnTF` factor into this? I can't seem to find much information on them but it seems to me that they should be facing similar rounding issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't exist because it doesn't make much practical sense.  Any inaccuracy you get from a specific computation will make your code do a different thing, even if `3.1415926535897932` and `3.1415926535897931` aren't really different. For example, this:

```
\fp_compare:nNnTF { sin(2pi) } = { 0 }
  { \TRUE } { \FALSE }
```

yields false, even though analytically it should be true.

Floating-point equality is generally the wrong operation.  Most of the time it works because floating-point engines are really good at their jobs, but if you feed them a tricky case it will get the wrong result.  In fact, when I used to write Fortran code, `gfortran` would raise a compile-time warning about floating-point equality (I don't have it installed to give an example, sorry).

And the issue with `\fp_case:nn` would be that it would use only equality tests to select a case, and that could work, yes, but it could also go wrong, so mainly for stability, it doesn't exist.

That said, we *do* have `\bool_case_true:n(TF)` and `\bool_case_false:n(TF)`, which you can use to emulate a `\fp_case:nn` which checks if a value matches within a set tolerance. Here's a proof-of-concept (no true/false branching implemented):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l_arets_tol_fp
\fp_set:Nn \l_arets_tol_fp { 1e-6 }
\cs_new:Npn \arets_fp_case:nn #1
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \__arets_fp_case:nn
      { \fp_eval:n {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__arets_fp_case:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_map_tokens:nn {#2}
      { \__arets_fp_case_split:nn {#1} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__arets_fp_case_split:nn #1#2
  { \__arets_fp_case:nnn {#1} #2 }
\cs_new:Npn \__arets_fp_case:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \fp_compare:nT
      {
        #1 > #2 - \l_arets_tol_fp &
        #1 < #2 + \l_arets_tol_fp
      }
      { \tl_map_break:n {#3} }
  }

% ------------ Test macro
\cs_new_protected:Npn \test #1
  {
    $
    \arets_fp_case:nn {#1}
      {
        { { pi }   { \pi } }
        { { exp(1) } { e } }
      }
    = \fp_eval:n {#1} $
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\test{3.1415926}

\test{2.7182818}

\test{1.6180339}
\end{document}
```

which prints:

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I know about the issues with rounding in `switch` statements in general, I was wondering exactly about this type of "precision-bounded" approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\str_case:nn` or `\str_case_e:nn` as long as all the floating points are in decimal representation.

You can also use `\token_case_meaning:Nn` as long as you are only comparing floating point variables.

Of course, the usual problems of testing floating point equality (as noted by Phelype Oleinik) still apply.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \__my_fp_case:nn #1#2
  { \str_case_e:en { \fp_to_decimal:n {#1} } {#2} }
\cs_new:Npn \__my_fp_case_test:n #1
  {
    \__my_fp_case:nn {#1}
      {
        { \fp_to_decimal:N \c_one_fp } { <code1> }
        { 2 } { <code2> }
        { \fp_to_decimal:n { 0.6 * 2 } } { <code3> }
        { \fp_to_decimal:n { 1.2 ^ 2 } } { <code4> }
      }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \fpcasetest { m }
  { \__my_fp_case_test:n {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\fpcasetest{1}

\fpcasetest{2}

\fpcasetest{1.2}

\fpcasetest{1.44}

\bigskip

% just for demonstration; please don't use ExplSyntax at document level
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \__my_fp_case_token_meaning:N #1
  {
    \token_case_meaning:Nn #1
      {
        \c_zero_fp { <code1> }
        \c_one_fp  { <code2> }
        \c_e_fp    { <code3> }
        \c_pi_fp   { <code4> }
      }
  }
\__my_fp_case_token_meaning:N \c_zero_fp
\par
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {1}
\__my_fp_case_token_meaning:N \l_tmpa_fp
\par
\__my_fp_case_token_meaning:N \c_e_fp
\par
\fp_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_fp \c_pi_fp
\__my_fp_case_token_meaning:N \l_tmpa_fp
\par
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]